# CloudFormation cloudwatch namespaces cannot be seen

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to create a `cloudwatch` alarm as below:

```
  503AlarmELB:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      AlarmDescription: "503 HTTP CODE Count is higher than 20"
      # AlarmName: !Join ["-", [ !Ref Namespace, !Ref Environment, "ALB-HTTPCode_ELB_503_Count" ]]
      AlarmActions:
      - Ref: ManagedCloudSNSTopic
      MetricName: "HTTPCode_ELB_503_Count"
      Namespace: TriAppsTestV2ApplicationELB
      Statistic: Average
      Period:
        Ref: 503AlarmPeriod
      EvaluationPeriods: 
        Ref: 503AlarmEvaluationPeriods
      Threshold: 
        Ref: 503AlarmThreshold
      ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold
      Dimensions:
      - Name: InternalALB
        Value:
          Ref: InternalAlbFullName
```

And in the `Namespace` I have given the value `TriAppsTestV2ApplicationELB`. But I cannot see this in the `metrics` section of the `CloudWatch` service. How can I find this `Namespace` ?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace for that matric is (from [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-cloudwatch-metrics.html#load-balancer-metrics-alb)):

```
Namespace: AWS/ApplicationELB
```

Comment: Hi, I thought when I give it a random name, it would create a new namespace by that name. But with my approach, It didn't create a new namespace nor gave an error

Comment: @JananathBanuka I can't be random name. It must be what I wrote it should be.